# Sort String Array As Int

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, arraylist, icomparer

Is there some way to use IComparer with ArrayList.Sort() to sort a group of strings as ints?

Comment: Do you mean strings like "1", "55"?

Answer (score 10):

If they are all strings, why are you using an ArrayList? If you're on .Net 2.0 or later,  `List<string>` is a *much* better choice.

If you're on .Net 3.5 or later:

```
var result = MyList.OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o.ToString() ) ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  Just create the appropriate comparer that does the conversion.

```
public class StringAsIntComparer : IComparer {
  public int Compare(object l, object r) {
    int left = Int32.Parse((string)l);
    int right = Int32.Parse((string)r);
    return left.CompareTo(right);
}
```

Comment: That's what I was about to answer!

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation based on Joel's solution

```
string[] strNums = {"111","32","33","545","1","" ,"23",null};
    var nums = strNums.Where( s => 
        {
        int result;
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && int.TryParse(s,out result);
        }
    )
    .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
    .OrderBy(n => n);

    foreach(int num in nums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
```